# Why can't I use &(vector<bool>)[0] by Rvalue of bool*?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, boolean, stdvector

```
#include<vector>
struct TYPE {
    int a, b, g, d;
    bool bl;
};
int main() {
    std::vector<TYPE> i;
    std::vector<bool> b;

    TYPE* ii = &i[0]; // can work with int, double, char and something else
    bool* bb = &b[0]; // compile error
}
```

why only bool can't do it?
I check TYPE can be int, double, char and user-defined-type.

Comment: As kmdreko pointed out, std::vector<bool> isn't actually a contiguous sequence of booleans in memory, it's a specialisation that uses 1 bit per bool

Comment: See also here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool for more details.

Comment: @kmdreko thx,vector<bool> is a bitset not an array of bools! I understand why It can't and how can I use this! thx a lot.

Comment: @tomalbrc thx! I should remeber this vector<bool> is deferent with bool[].